# Central Admin Error Due to Low Disk Space

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration

The `C:\` drive of the server where the central admin is hosted has been consumed unexpectedly by the service account. Currently, it is holding 24 GB of files. When I browsed through files I found that there are a lot of files under

> Users->Acc_name->AppData->Local->IsolatedStorage.

I am unable to view it in the explorer and hence I am unable to delete it directly. All the files are having `.ris` extension.

Please help me in understanding what kind of folder / file is this and how can I clear the space. CA is throwing an error and none of the applications are opening due to zero space availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like developers or any custom solution or 3rd party solutions using the Isolated Storage for their code, which cause space issue.

> isolated storage is a data storage mechanism that provides isolation
>   and safety by defining standardized ways of associating code with
>   saved data. Standardization provides other benefits as well.
>   Administrators can use tools designed to manipulate isolated storage
>   to configure file storage space, set security policies, and delete
>   unused data.

You can cap the storage space etc. These files are may be in use that's why you are unable to delete them.

I would recommend move this storage location from C drive to others.
Read more about this: [Isolated Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)